# Nothing boots (previously Windows 7 / lubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, windows-7

I tried to install xubuntu on a machine that had Windows 7 alongside lubuntu

The error I made is that I clicked by error erasing everything and install xubuntu. But I stopped at the next window that asks for time zone. Then I shut down everything and nothing boots any more now. I only get the BIOS and then black screen. Period.

I tried repairing the grub but that doesn't work.

Here is the BootInfo report :

```
> Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 9Feb2015]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03 2014-10-06................................................2....0............A20 gate n
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 2006944 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux/syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   968,577,023   968,574,976  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         968,579,070   976,771,071     8,192,002   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         968,579,072   976,771,071     8,192,000  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15513354240 bytes, 30299520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          8,064    30,299,519    30,291,456   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        37d955dc-0f63-4369-9e50-56b4bd6179ad   ext4       
/dev/sda5        30492670-43a2-483a-9c3f-a116793f9f42   swap       
/dev/sdb1        314A-87E9                              vfat       PHILIPS UFD
/dev/sr0         2015-05-24-06-43-47-00                 iso9660    UBCD535

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 15 15:32 ata-ST9500325AS_S2W8HL2W -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 ata-ST9500325AS_S2W8HL2W-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 ata-ST9500325AS_S2W8HL2W-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 ata-ST9500325AS_S2W8HL2W-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 15 15:23 ata-TSSTcorp_DVD+_-RW_SN-208BB_R8KL6GPBB07440 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 15 15:32 usb-Philips_USB_Flash_Drive_0708521B1790C741-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 usb-Philips_USB_Flash_Drive_0708521B1790C741-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 15 15:32 wwn-0x11842574390115979264x -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 wwn-0x11842574390115979264x-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 wwn-0x11842574390115979264x-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 15 15:32 wwn-0x11842574390115979264x-part5 -> ../../sda5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=37d955dc-0f63-4369-9e50-56b4bd6179ad /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=30492670-43a2-483a-9c3f-a116793f9f42 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

========================= sdb1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path 
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 ldlinux.c32                        :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/chain.c32                 :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/ldlinux.c32               :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/libcom32.c32              :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/libutil.c32               :  not a COM32/COM32R module
 syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  not a COM32/COM32R module

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/5041/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 10519: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[55000]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 10519: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2015-08-15__15h32 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa33
boot-sav version : 4ppa33
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa47~saucy
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa33
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 15.04, vivid, Ubuntu, i686)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
bootkbd=fr-latin1 console-setup/layoutcode=fr console-setup/variantcode=nodeadkeys locale=fr_FR noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true file=/cdrom/preseed/xubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz splash -- maybe-ubiquity
ls: impossible d'accéder à /home/usr/.config: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: UUID="37d955dc-0f63-4369-9e50-56b4bd6179ad" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c9964a82-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="PHILIPS UFD" UUID="314A-87E9" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="31a17072-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="30492670-43a2-483a-9c3f-a116793f9f42" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c9964a82-05"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2015-05-24-06-43-47-00" LABEL="UBCD535" TYPE="iso9660"

sfdisk: Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not EFI-compatible.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv      nogrub, no-docgrub,     no-update-grub, 32,     no-boot,        no-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot,     fstab-without-efi,      no-nt,  no-winload,     no-recov-nor-hid,       no-bmgr,        notwinboot,     nopakmgr,       nogrubinstall,  no---usr,       fstab-without-usr,      not-sep-usr,    standard,       farbios,        /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.

sda     : not-GPT,      BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,         not-usb,        no-os,  2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA ST9500325AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  496GB  496GB   primary   ext4            boot
2      496GB   500GB  4194MB  extended
5      496GB   500GB  4194MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: Philips USB Flash Drive (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      4129kB  15.5GB  15.5GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: TSSTcorp DVD+-RW SN-208BB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 627MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST9500325AS:;
1:1049kB:496GB:496GB:ext4::boot;
2:496GB:500GB:4194MB:::;
5:496GB:500GB:4194MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Philips USB Flash Drive:;
1:4129kB:15.5GB:15.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;

BYT;
/dev/sr0:627MB:scsi:2048:2048:unknown:TSSTcorp DVD+-RW SN-208BB:;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL       MODEL            UUID
sda   disk          465,8G             ST9500325AS
sda1  part ext4     461,9G                              37d955dc-0f63-4369-9e50-56b4bd6179ad
sda2  part              1K
sda5  part swap       3,9G                              30492670-43a2-483a-9c3f-a116793f9f42
sdb   disk           14,5G             USB Flash Drive
sdb1  part vfat      14,5G PHILIPS UFD                  314A-87E9
sr0   rom  iso9660  598,2M UBCD535     DVD+-RW SN-208BB 2015-05-24-06-43-47-00
loop0 loop squashfs 934,4M

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sda      1  0  0 running
sda1     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2     1  0  0
sda5     1  0  0         [SWAP]
sdb      1  0  1 running
sdb1     1  0  1         /cdrom
sr0      1  0  1 running
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs


=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=2007456k,nr_inodes=206942,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=403848k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=403848k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fb1 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hpet hugepages i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-10 i2c-11 i2c-12 i2c-13 i2c-14 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 i2c-9 initctl input kmsg kvm log mapper mcelog media0 mei0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda5 sdb sdb1 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom usb v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 xconsole zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control
=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     395M   12M  384M   3% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat       15G  1.2G   14G   8% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  935M  935M     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   2.0G  195M  1.8G  10% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G   80K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     395M   44K  395M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sda1      ext4      455G   70M  432G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/loop0: 934.4 MiB, 979812352 bytes, 1913696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9964a82

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 968577023 968574976 461.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       968579070 976771071   8192002   3.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       968579072 976771071   8192000   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15513354240 bytes, 30299520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31a17072

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     8064 30299519 30291456 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


No OS or WinEFI system
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
No OS or WinEFI system


=================== Default settings of Boot Repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  repair-filesystems


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the MBR.
Additional repair will be performed:  repair-filesystems


Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

fsck -fyM /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For temporary if you want to start then make bootable system of windows 7 and choose repair system->startup repair. This will automatically fix w7 startup

Comment: I tried this also. It didn't work.